# What do the different horses do?

Tags: west-of-loathing

There are several horses that you can choose in West of Loathing: Normal, Crazy, Pale, and Dark. Other than having a cosmetically different horse appear in adventuring areas, is there a mechanical or narrative effect for choosing a different horse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dark Horse will sometimes allow you to bypass an encounter found while moving in the world map. You get an option to flee with the text "Dark Horse" next to it, like this:

[image: screenshot of Dark Horse option to run off from an encounter]

I have not seen any screens that claim to be caused by the Crazy Horse, but it seems like the Crazy Horse discovers new locations faster than the other ones.

As mentioned in other answers, the Pale Horse will trigger an event where you get one of the Nex Mex necromancy skillbooks. It's unclear if this means that the Pale Horse is required to get all the necromancy skills or that the Pale Horse helps you get those skills earlier than they would normally be discovered.

Answer (score 2):

The Pale Horse will sometimes revive you from fainting after you lose a battle, allowing you to keep fighting even after you passed out from being angry. It will say "{Horse-Name} woke you up by whispering terrifying secrets in your ear."

Answer (score -1):

I choses the pale horse and I think I was able to get a spell because of it. When I was wandering it said I was suddenly surrounded by creepy trees and then I followed my horse and it showed me to a necromancy book. The spell it gave me was called Grinnin' Skull at level one it does 10 spooky damage at the cost of one ap. I'm looking forward to see if the ghost horse leads me to more evil spells! MWAHAHAHA!!!

Comment: The Nex Mex spellbooks are not just from the Pale Horse, I was able to get them on a character with the Crazy Horse

Comment: Yes, I know. But I think there's maybe a spell or two you could get from only the pale horse. But if the crazy horse gets you to follow them through some creepy trees to a book on a pedestal let me know otherwise because the dialogue seemed extremely specific to the pale horse.

Comment: Yeah I think you may be right on that, I'm not sure if the nex mex books are all in the same places and the pale horse is giving you extra or if it is just giving duplicates earlier